# PassportJS not saving session in local strategy

Tags: node.js, session, authentication, passport.js, passport-local

I'm loosely following the tutorial [here](https://blog.risingstack.com/node-hero-node-js-authentication-passport-js/), and I'm not sure why it's not working. Logging in will work fine -- it accepts and rejects me exactly how I'd expect, it will just not save the session, so visiting any links after will say that I am not authenticated.

Vivaldi dev panel says that [no cookies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvGyy.png) or [sessions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uqu9v.png) are saved. I have set it up to save my sessions in redis and user authentication in PostgreSQL, and both databases are connected to fine.

Here is the relevant code:

index.js:

```
const express = require('express');

const passport = require('passport'); 
const session = require('express-session');

const Redis = require('ioredis');
const RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);

const bodyParser   = require('body-parser');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

const auth      = require("./app/authenticate");
const config    = require('./config');

const app = express();

var redis_client = new Redis({
  host: config.redisStore.host,
  port: config.redisStore.port,
  lazyConnect: true
});
redis_client.connect().catch(function(err) {
  throw err;
});

app.use(cookieParser(config.redisStore.secret));
app.use(session({
  cookie : {
    maxAge: 36000000000,
    secure: true
  },
  secret: config.redisStore.secret,
  store: new RedisStore({ client: redis_client }),
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

auth.init.initPassport();
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
  successRedirect: '/testroute',
  failureRedirect: '/'
}));

var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false});
app.get("/testroute", passport.authenticationMiddleware(), urlencodedParser, function(req, res) {
    res.send("You are authenticated!");
});

app.listen(8080);
```

/app/authenticate/init.js:

```
const passport      = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const scrypt        = require("scrypt");

const auth = require("./userfunctions");

const authenticationMiddleware = function() {
  return function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
      return next();
    }
    res.send('ERR: You are not authenticated!');
  };
}

module.exports = {
  initPassport: function() {
    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
      done(null, user);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
      auth.getUserById(id, done);
    });

    passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'pwd',
      },
      function(username, password, done) {
        auth.login(username, function(err, user) {
          if (err) {console.log(err); return done(err);}
          if (!user) {return done(null, false);}
          if (!scrypt.verifyKdfSync(user.password, password)) {return done(null, false);}
          return done(null, user);
        });
      }
    ));

    passport.authenticationMiddleware = authenticationMiddleware;
  }
};
```

There are a few other files in /app/authenticate, which are index.js (just adds all the other things to modules.exports) and userfunctions.js, which just includes login and signup functions. I can post these if you need.

I have also omitted the config file, which is just database credentials for PostgreSQL and redis. Finally I have excluded test.html which is served when you GET /, and is just a test HTML login and signup form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use express-session npm module to save your session value.

Below are the steps-

1. npm install express-session
2. In your startup JS file write below code
   var expressSession = require('express-session');
   app.use(expressSession({secret: 'yourothersecretcode', saveUninitialized: true, resave: true}));
3. Now you can use req.session in your code

req.session is just a json object that gets persisted by the express-session middleware, using a store of your choice e.g. Mongo or Redis.